# Initialized empty numpy array is not really empty (contains zeros)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In order to store many 3D points coordinates tuples in a `numpy.ndarray` I initialize an empty numpy array before entering a loop for each of some features.

To do so, I currently do this before entering the loop:

```
import numpy as np
pointsarrray = np.empty((1,3))
```

but this results in an array which is all but empty:

```
array([[  5.30498948e-315,   0.00000000e+000,   7.81250000e-003]])
```

When filling `pointsarray` in my loop after, I do this:

```
pointsarray = np.vstack((pointsarray, [np.array(myPoint)]))
```

(it also works with np.append)

and I finally need to delete the **first** line of the array after exiting the loop because this first line always contains the values from the initialization step!

It's not a big deal but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to achieve a **really** empty array, I mean; with nothing inside it (it shows 1 row yet, I can not figure out why) but at the right dimensions?

Comment: What's your definition of **really** empty array?

Comment: An empty array has zero dimensions. An array with non-zero dimensions is not empty.

Comment: Are you aware of the underlying basics? E.g. uninitialized C-arrays? Allocating memory and pre-setting memory are two different things. And empty just means, you are not initializing it with values (so any garbage from memory will live there until overwritten).

Comment: <at>Divakar : My definition in this case would have been an array with nothing in it, i.e. no 1st row as my example shown. <at>sascha : No I'm not really aware of these memory underlying basics but it's alway good to have some clues; thanks.

Comment: Well, you asked for a row and see stuff from memory (because of no init). Psidom's answer shows what you maybe did try to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the shape to be `(0, 3)` so you have the correct number of columns to stack but have actually no data inside:

```
import numpy as np
pointsarrray = np.empty((0,3))

pointsarrray
# array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
```

Comment: What's the most annoying here is not the simplicity and efficiency of the answer but rather the fact I didn't think of it by myself (I've tried so many more complicated stuff...) anyway; big thanks

Comment: Is there a numpy function returning a shapeless (hence without initialized coefficients as there are no coeffficient if the shape is not specified) array ? (Like a default constructor doing really nothing.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's the name that is confusing you but [`numpy.empty`s documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) explains what is happening:

> Return a new array of given shape and type, without initializing entries.

So it just doesn't initialize the entries (sometimes they are **random** sometimes they are **zero**) but empty refers only to the value of the entries not to the shape of the array.

---

However it's really bad for performance to create an array by appending or stacking. Just collect them in a list and create the array afterwards:

```
pointsarray = [np.array(myPoint)]

# ...

pointsarray = np.array(pointsarray)  # or np.stack(pointsarray, axis=...) whatever you need.
```